# If $E$ and $F$ are two topological vector spaces Hausdorff, $\hat{E} \times \hat{F} \cong (E\times F)\hat{}$.

Tags: topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces, complete-spaces

I want to prove that: If $E$ and $F$ are two topological vector spaces Hausdorff, then there is a canonical isomorphism between  $\hat{E} \times \hat{F}$ and $(E\times F)\hat{}$.

For this I thought about using Theorem 5.2 from, that is, by Theorem 5.2 of [1] there are completes Hausdorff topological vector spaces $ \hat{E} $ and $ \hat{F} $ such that the canonical injections $ i_E: E \longrightarrow \hat{E} $ and $ i_F: F \longrightarrow \hat{F} $ are isomorphisms.

On the other hand, since $ E $ and $ F $ are Hausdorff's topological vector spaces, then $ H: = E \times F $ is Hausdorff's topological vector space as well, with $ E \times F $ provided with the product topology. Thus, again by Theorem 5.2 of [1], there is a complete Hausdoff topological vector space $ \hat {H} = (E \times F) \hat{} $ such that the natural injection $ i_H: H \longrightarrow \hat{H} $ is isomorphism.

But from then on I was unable to proceed to prove what I desire.

See Theorem 5.2 in the page 41 of [1].

[[1]](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kClvQ1qk9r8C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) Trèves, F.**Topological vector spaces, distributions and kernels**. Unabridged republication of the 1967 original.Dover Publications, Inc., Mineola, NY,  2006.

Comment: Sorry, but what is $\hat E$ here?

Comment: I guess the obvious $\widehat{E} \times \widehat{F} \cong E\times F \cong \widehat{E\times F}$ does not work?

Comment: @Reveillark See Theorem 5.2 in the page 41 of [1].

Comment: @PrudiiArca Thus, given any $ (\hat{u}, \hat {v}) \in \hat {E} \times \hat {F} $ there is a single $(u, v) \in E \times F $ such that
$$ (i_E (u), i_F (v)) = (\hat {u}, \hat {v}). $$
In these terms, the application is well defined $ f: \hat {E} \times \hat {F} \longrightarrow  E \times F $ given by
  $$ f( \hat{u}, \hat{v})=(u, v)$$

Comment: @PrudiiArca Defining $ g: = i_H \circ f $, it follows that $ g $ is isomorphism, as it is composed of isomorphisms. Therefore, there is an isomorphism between $ \hat {E} \times \hat{F} $ and $ (E \times F) \hat {} $.

Comment: @PrudiiArca It does not work? Is this reasoning right?

Comment: I am worried about your assumptions that *the canonical injections *i_E : E \rightarrow \widehat{E}* are isomorphisms. If they are then there should be an isomorphism $\widehat{E}\times \widehat{F} \overset{(i_E\times i_F)^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} E \times F \overset{i_H}{\longrightarrow} \widehat{E \times F}$. But then the $\widehat{(-)}$ construction (whatever it is) does not very much sense to me.

Comment: But the canonical injections are clearly isomorphisms, by the Theorem 5.2, in [1].

Comment: And the $(E\times F)\hat{}$ for me is clearly, since $E\times F$ is topological vector space Hausdorff too and by Theorem 5.2, in [1].